# Ada 202x proposal @ restriction rationale?

Tags: ada

I have a question about the proposed Ada 202x standard. Specifically I am wondering about the constraints on the target name (`@`) feature. It appears as though this feature will only be available in assignment statements and not in record or array aggregates. What is the rationale behind this restriction?

To explain why I think it would be useful to broaden the scope of target name. Compare these two functions.

Implementation as I understand the proposed standard:

```
function Mutate (State : Some_State) return Some_State is (State with delta
    Internal_Component => (State.Internal_Component with delta
        Component_Array => (State.Internal_Component.Component_Array with delta
            Array_Index => State.Internal_Component.Component_Array (Array_Index) + 1,
            Other_Index => State.Internal_Component.Component_Array (Other_Index) - 1)));
```

If the target name feature were extended to aggregates then this could be:

```
function Mutate (State : Some_State) return Some_State is (State with delta
    Internal_Component => (@ with delta   --  @ is State.Internal_Component
        Component_Array => (@ with delta  --  @ is State.Internal_Component.Component_Array
            Array_Index => @ + 1,         --  @ is State.Internal_Component.Component_Array (Array_Index)
            Other_Index => @ - 1)));      --  @ is State.Internal_Component.Component_Array (Other_Index)
```

If delta aggregates could implicitly nest this could result in the very clean:

```
function Clean_Mutate (State : Some_State) return Some_State is (State with delta
        Internal_Component.Component_Array => @ with delta (
            Array_Index => @ + 1,
            Other_Index => @ - 1));
```

Of course as written one could use:

```
function Mutate (State : Some_State) return Some_State is
    Result : Some_State := State;
begin
    Result.Internal_Component.Component_Array (Array_Index) := @ + 1;
    Result.Internal_Component.Component_Array (Other_Index) := @ - 1;
    return Result;
end Mutate;
```

But this is still not quite as clean, and it severely hampers target name's use in non-assignment expressions.

Comment: PS: Should someone with enough reputation create the "Ada-202x" tag yet? It's on its way and there are bound to be more questions about it. "Ada-2012" is already a tag.

Comment: I don’t believe there’s anyone here qualified to answer this. Try the [Ada-Comment mailing list](http://www.ada-auth.org/comment.html), though I think you’ll be too late to affect anything for 2020. In any case, this isn’t a proper Stack Overflow question.

Comment: I'd say that is probably the answer to my question then. I wasn't sure how exactly to join the discussion I was reading [here](http://www.ada-auth.org/cgi-bin/cvsweb.cgi/ai12s/ai12-0125-3.txt?rev=1.21&raw=N). All I knew is that it didn't address my question. Thanks.

Comment: I will say your desired example seems like a different set of mechanics than the intended usage.  In an assignment statement, the @ sign represents the LHS of the assignment.  In your desired example, you want it to represent an input to the assignment (state : some_state).  The LHS would be the "return value", which is why your final example would work (Result is a LHS of an assignment).  What you are suggesting would require the @ symbol to mean different things in different contexts.  I don't work on the ARG, so that is just my interpretation though (grain of salt obviously)

Comment: It would be ambiguous in assignment with delta aggregate or with delta aggregate within delta aggregate. Maybe most of these cases can be resolved with special @-overloading rules, but Ada is designed to avoid ambiguities and complex resolution rules.